# Is there a size limit to a Android Gradle build?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I have an Android project with 3000 photo's that needs to be available offline. When I include all the photo's in the build, the build fails. When I remove some of them, the build succeeds.
I have put the photo's in two dynamic modules that download at install time.

Here is the gradle scan for reference: https://scans.gradle.com/s/nn6eo527qvge6

Is this purely a size issue and if so, how do I get around that?

Comment: What is the size when it succeeds?

Comment: The primary app is < 150Mb and the Photo's has been successfully compiled up to 1 Gb

Comment: Have you considered https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/asset-delivery  (or https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/dynamic-delivery) ? :)

Comment: @MartinMarconcini, I'm actually using dynamic delivery, but can't get clarity on what these module size limits are.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this purely a size issue

Probably.

> how do I get around that?

Start by moving your photos out of `res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/` and into `assets/` and adjust your code that consumes the photos to match.

Then, see what the resulting APK size is and compare it with the size limits for your intended app distribution channel (e.g., 100MB limit for the Play Store). If you exceed that limit, you will need to work through alternative approaches (e.g., [APK expansion files](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files)).

Comment: Isn't the expansion files old tech? I'm using dynamic modules that download at install time that are separate from the main bundle. (Edited the question)

Comment: Dynamic Modules is the way, starting in 2021 you'll need a bundle, not APK, and the max size is 150Mb for the former.

Comment: @Stephan: How you accomplish it will depend on your app distribution channel and their policies. My point is that you will need to take their policies and remediation efforts into account.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini, what I'm not clear on is: If I keep the bundle download size to < 150Mb, but the dynamic modules are > 1 Gb, will that be ok?

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes, I'm trying to take that into account and that's why I've put the photo's in dynamic modules. But I don't understand the build errors and if they are size related, I don't have clarity on what these size limits for dynamic bundles are.

Comment: I think there are two issues. Dynamic Modules will warn the user if the module is >10MB I think, but also Dynamic Modules are Gradle Modules... not "zip files with a lot of assets", so if (and I don't know this) a module cannot be, say greater than 150MB, I'm positive a Dynamic Module will have the same limitation, but I couldn't find this information in [the best practices Google recommends](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/ux-guidelines).

Comment: @Stephan: "But I don't understand the build errors and if they are size related" -- the build errors, AFAICT, is because you have too much space consumed by resources. Move the photos to `assets/`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, but then I loose the benefits of having bundles and different sized photos, won't I? Or is this then just a limitation and I should rather put in high quality photo's everywhere?

Comment: @Stephan: I don't know what you would consider a non-high-quality "photo" to be. The drawable densities are designed for icons and other small bits of artwork.

Comment: Whatever you do, you should certainly include these as /assets and not in the _drawables_, I agree with @CommonsWare.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [CommonsWare's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64037800/2684), I think the way you should do this is not by using `Dynamic Modules` but by using `asset delivery`. It's kinda "marketed" as a "for games" thing, but it's not limited at all by that.

The idea behind [asset-delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery) is that you have a pack of assets (images in your case) that you need for your app to function.

This "pack" of assets can be requested at install time, or later "on demand". All this is confusing because [Dynamic Delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/dynamic-delivery) sounds very similar. However, as stated at the top of the [asset-delivery page](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery), they use *Different APIs*.

In all honestly, I haven't used Asset Delivery, so take it with a grain of salt, and keep the considerations at hand, for example (and I [quote](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-java)):

> If the download is larger than 150 MB and the user is not on Wi-Fi, the download does not start until the user explicitly gives their consent to proceed with the download using a mobile data connection. Similarly, if the download is large and the user loses Wi-Fi, the download is paused and explicit consent is required to proceed using a mobile data connection.

Comment: I'll try the asset-delivery route and see if that works for my use case and revert here.